# Is there any reason spoilers would deploy just after liftoff?

Tags: takeoff, boeing-747, spoilers

I was watching this video of a 747-8F taking off.

http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x273atd

Just after liftoff the air brakes and ground spoilers deploy on the left wing causing a sharp roll to the left. You then see the left retract and the right deploy rolling right. Then on the left again to correct.

[image]

The second and 3rd deployments on the video are obviously commanded by the pilot to correct for the roll.

Watching several other videos of the 747-8 taking off I don't see any others with spoilers out at any time during takeoff. On 747-8 are the spoilers connected to the ailerons to help with roll? If so, does it take a strong wheel movement to cause this? Why would they have deployed so quickly after takeoff, was this a control input by the pilot? Why would he make such an input?

It looks like they narrowly escaped disaster on this takeoff.

Comment: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2783901/Captain-dramatically-dips-wings-just-seconds-highly-skilled-stunt.html It's an empty plane on its maiden flight, waving bye bye - no disaster there.

Comment: @Sanchises Ah. Intentional maneuver. Nice. Still looks pretty crazy to me. That's a significant roll to be doing at such low speed. [The things we do to show off.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=182AepOJjMs)

Comment: Yeah, the Daily Mail called it a "highly skilled manoeuvre", but since it's the Daily Mail, the captain may well have had to explain himself to management for toying with their fresh plane.